# If an entire function $f$ can be written as a polynomial in a ball around $z_0$ for every $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$, then $f$ is actually a polynomial.

Tags: complex-analysis

I wonder how we prove the statement in the title.

Actually, this is needed for solving the following problem.

> Let $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be an entire function.
> Suppose that for every $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ the power series expansion
> $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }a_k(z-z_0)^k$ of $f$ around $z_0$ satisfies that
> there is $k \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t $a_k = 0$. Show that $f$ is a
> polynomial.

I could show that $f$ can be written in a polynomial in each ball using the Identity Theorem, with the fact "an uncountable closed set contains an accumulation point."

However, I'm stuck there, and cannot proceed more from here to show that $f$ is indeed a polynomial on $\mathbb{C}$.

It seems like the Identity Theorem could be reused inductively here, but the problem occurs when setting a domain of two polynomials of two connected balls. (What I tried  to show was any two connected balls eventually have the same polynomial expression of $f$ so that the statement could be automatically true.)

How should I show that the statement is true with the Identity Theorem, or is there an alternative way to do this?

Update with my work:

Let $P_0$ be the polynomial expression of $f$ on $B(z_0,r)$.
Assume that $P_0$ is entire (In other words, assume that it is defined on whole $\mathbb{C}$.)

Now, let $Z=\left \{ z\in \mathbb{C}:f(z)=P_0(z) \right \}$.

Observe that, $z_0 \in Z$, and in $Z \setminus \{z_0\}$, there is a sequence $\left \{ z_n \right \}_{n=2}^{\infty } $ s.t $z_n = z_0 + r/n$.

This shows that, $z_0$ is an accumulation point in $Z$, hence by the identity Thm, $f(z)=P_0(z)$ for any $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the polynomial has degree $n$ then $f^{(n+1)}$ is an entire function which vanishes on the given ball. By the identity theorem it vanishes everywhere. Hence, $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually, I just updated the question with my additional work. Does that sound right?

Comment: @john All polynomials are entire functions. Except for this your argument is fine.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is entire so it is equal to its power series (at any point) on all of $\mathbb{C}$. It is therefore a polynomial.